# VBA vs VB.net performance with Excel database

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, pivot-table

I have sheets with `80*15*5 = 6000` data points, generated from Excel Pivot Tables. I have to make a choice between programming in `Visual Basic for Applications` and `Visual Basic.net`, or working with Excel formulas. All of the data must be analysed in two different ways, different things must be calculated, and the user should be able to generate an output in a user-friendly way without having any knowledge of the data.

An small example program with a loop in a loop in a loop cost 100 seconds in VBA and 34 in Visual Basic.net. If I'm going to work with Excel formulas, I also have to program multiple functions because they don't exist in Excel yet. Right now I'm doing this for another program and this is pretty slow on my company's computers.

The running time makes me choose for VB.net, but will this still be quicker when an external VB.net created program has to make a connection to the Excel database? The relatively easy way of using this data in VBA makes me want to choose for VBA.

Besides this all, my guess is that working with Excel formulas isn't the most handy way, because the `80` and `15` in the formula above can become bigger over time.

Is there something to say in general about why I should choose which solution?

Comment: You mention `[a] small example program with a loop in a loop in a loop` which is very inefficient to begin with.  What specifically are you trying to do?  Can you post the code and some sample data with expected results so that we might suggest alternatives? Or perhaps head on over to CodeReview to have your code improved on for efficiency?   As for your very general question about which solution to go with, it's hard to say without more information.  Generally speaking though, VB.Net will still be quicker, but we can probably make your code or formulas much more efficient

Comment: I'd say go with the one you are most comfortable and familiar with.  Vb.NET should be the most flexible and  powerful, but doesnt mean much if you arent able to write clean, perfomant code.

Comment: The small program was just somthing random I made to  compare the running time. Plutonix, that makes sense. I put a lot of time in VBA before so that's the easiest for me, but I like to improve my knowledge of VB.net as well. This would make me choose for VBA though

Comment: VBA is going to be better for _coding_ because of the highly specific intellisense and IDE. You can also connect to an Excel workbook using ADODB in VBA if you want to improve speed - I see no advantage for vb.net here unless there is something external and extremely complex that VBA can't do efficiently.

Comment: @MacroMan You can get the same level of intellisense and a MUCH better IDE with .NET and  Visual Studio than with standard VBA. Don't know why you would say that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the IDE is much better in VS, no doubt about that - but we're talking about programming for a specific application, with specific libraries and dependencies, which is _exactly_ what VBA and it's native IDE are made for. As someone who programs using both, I would always go to VBA first for office automation

Comment: a) If I wasn't going to use VBA then I would jump to C#, not VB.Net b) **Anything** involving looping through a worksheet's cells is goin to be comparatively slow; learn in-memory processing methods using variant arrays if you want to write efficient code reardless of the route you take.

Comment: @MacroMan Once you make the reference to the Excel PIA, you will have all the intellisense that you would have in VBA.

Comment: Side note... Excel is not a database. Just sayin'.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, the point I'm making is that it's already there in the VBA environment (assuming the code is also being written in Excel) along with your object explorers etc without having to 'set anything up' so to speak. VS is undoubtedly better if you know how to get what you want from it, but in my personal experience - people are put off moving from VBA to VS because of the learning curve. Anyway, point being I'm not arguing that VS _isn't_ a better IDE, just that there's no specific advantage in this scenario for it over VBA

Comment: @MacroMan You said "VBA is going to be better for coding because of the highly specific intellisense and IDE." and that's just not true since VS will provide the same intellisence and a much better IDE. You don't have to "set anything up". As with any work in .NET, you must reference the assembly you wish to work with. That's all that's needed to get all this.

Comment: And this is why, questions like this are not for this forum.  When asking for opinions, everyone has one.

Comment: Except that this isn't an opinion. How Visual Studio works is a fact.

Answer (score 2):

**Hands down, you should stick with VBA** because when you use .NET to connect to "unmanaged" (non .NET) applications, you will have to manage memory much more actively than if you just stick with VBA. .NET to Excel uses "Runtime Callable Wrappers" behind the scenes so that the two architectures can communicate, but they use different memory management mechanisms.

With Excel in particular, many objects are returned from method calls, but you don't have to do anything with them. If you aren't aware of these (and that's pretty easy to do), those objects will stay in memory and keep Excel alive even after the .NET application has been terminated. Cleaning up after all these objects involves many calls to `System.Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`.

As for the performance issue you mentioned (loop in loop in loop), that's just (pardon me) bad programming practice in any language. There is rarely a need to do something like this and if you are doing it, you should probably re-think your approach.

Additionally, it's VERY IMPORTANT to understand that VB.NET and VBA are entirely different languages, even though they appear to be very similar on the surface. Best-practices and common techniques from VBA should NOT be carried over to VB.NET. If you are unfamiliar with .NET, you'll want to do some serious research first.

Really, the only reason to go with .NET to Excel is if .NET offered some functionality that you can't get with VBA, but given that this doesn't seem to be the case, sticking with VBA will be a much simpler and, as long as you properly optimize your code, efficient solution in the long run.